# UI Button doesn't disappear when deactivating parent in hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a simple main menu page with this hierarchy:

```
MainMenu (an empty game object)
 ↳ Canvas
  ↳ PlayButton (a TextMeshPro Button)
```

I want the button to deactivate the 'MainMenu' object in the hierarchy when clicked, thus hiding its Canvas child and the Button along with it. To do this, I'm providing the MainMenu object reference to the Button's OnClick() callback and calling 'GameObject.SetActive' to false when clicked.

[image: Hierarchy with OnClick setting shown]

My problem is that when I click the button, the MainMenu hierarchy get grayed out in the editor but the Button sticks around with its yellow Highlighted color shown. It does disappear if I change the display resolution while still in Play mode (maybe forcing a refresh?), but I can't figure out why deactivating the MainMenu wouldn't make it refresh in the same way.

[image: Hierarchy greyed out, play button not hidden]

I've tried calling SetActive(false) on the PlayButton and the Canvas themselves- I also tried setting enabled = false on them, but the Button appearance behaves the same. From everything I've read, calling SetActive(false) should hide whatever gameObject I call it on, so I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found my own mistake. The Camera's `Clear Flags` setting was `Don't Clear`, so even calling Destroy(gameObject) on it didn't remove it from the screen.

Setting the Camera to use `ClearFlags: Solid Color` fixed the problem.

Comment: Just goes to show how dangerous changing defaults can be without fully understanding what the changes affect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a button in your grid that is displaying. When the game is playing, after you click to turn off the button, go to the scene tab, click the yellow button and see where that object is.

If in doubt (For testing purposes only) delete the button on click and if you see something else then it is obviously not that button.

Comment: Ah, I don't think it's worth a screenshot but the Grid object doesn't contain any buttons. I can delete it and I still get the same behavior.

I did try your button deletion test though: I added a script to the PlayButton to call Destroy(gameObject) on OnDisable(), which does succeed in deleting it from the hierarchy, but it still appears in the render.